# cakephp 1.3 sql group formatting

Tags: cakephp

I have a table in cakephp, containing box_id and quantity columns.
If I run this query:

```
$a = $this->Order->query('SELECT SUM(quantity) AS q FROM order_boxes GROUP BY box_id ');
```

I get always a strange array:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [q] => 242
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [q] => 22
            )

    )

)
```

I would get a simple table (as SQL does indeed) like:

```
 [box_id],[quantity]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
```

$a = $this->Order->query('SELECT box_id, SUM(quantity) AS q FROM order_boxes GROUP BY box_id ');

Comment: Same result. Nothing changed. I think it is impossible to get rid of this kind of formatting without using a custom function.